# Dual of a Nonlinear Convex Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

I am struggling in formulating the dual of a very simple problem:

\begin{align}
\max_{x_{i},y_{j}} \sum_{i=1}^{I}c_{i}x_{i} - \sum_{j=1}^{J}(\delta_{j}y_{j}+\gamma_{j}y_{j}^{2}) \hspace{0.2in} \\
s.t \hspace{0.2in} \sum_{i=1}^{I}a_{ij}x_{i}\leq y_{j}\hspace{0.1in}\forall\hspace{0.1in}j,\hspace{0.1in}y_{j}\geq 0,\hspace{0.1in}x_{i}\geq 0 
\end{align}

Furthermore, all the parameters $c_{i},\delta_{j},\gamma_{j},a_{ij}$ are strictly positive, such that the problem is concave.

When the problem is linear (all $\delta_{j}$ are equal to 0), the dual is easy to compute. However, once I add the quadratic term, I am not really sure how to proceed.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need a specific dual? Do you need ALL constraints to have dual variables, or are you free to chose?

Comment: @AlexShtoff , in principle, I just want the first set of capacity constraints. Although, my current approach also adds the multiplier in the non-negativity constraints for $y_{j}$.